# Query not excluding people with certain privilege

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like this:
table Person_by_Privileges:

```
PersonID Last  First Facility Department Privilages
1        Hoff  Mary  S        P          abc
1        Hoff  Mary  S        P          cde
1        Hoff  Mary  S        P          def
2        Smith Georg S        P          abc
2        Smith Georg S        P          cde
```

I'm trying to get the query to only return Georg Smith, since he doesn't have Privilege for def.  I'm having trouble doing that, since it's different query lines.  I'm trying this:

```
SELECT distinct [PersonID]
      ,[Last]
      ,[First]
      ,[Facility]
      ,[Department]
      ,Privilages = STUFF(
                 (SELECT ',' + pp.Privilages FROM Person_by_Privilages pp where Facility='S' FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
               ) 
  FROM [Person_by_Privilages] pp  
  where
  Facility='S'
  AND
  (
     Department like ('%p%')
  )
  and 
  Privilages NOT LIKE ('%def%')
```

But when I look at the first person (Hoff) for that query, that shouldn't be returned because they do have Privilage for def, I do get that person in the results:

```
PersonID Last First Facility Dept Privilages
1        Hoff Mary  S        P    (list of her Privilages appended together..does include the def)
```

Comment: I thought I would note that you seem to be spelling the word "privileges" inconsistently. I don't know if that's correctable or if it has contributed to any of your problems.

Comment: Your subquery is appending the results for all people. Why are you even using that query in the first place? Isn't the result you want already part of the outer/main query?

Comment: Sorry, it's just me typing the question.  I think I fixed it there

Comment: @shawnt00 - the main outer query includes all privilages for each person.  I just need people without the privilege of def. Appending all the privilages together doesn't accomplish that.

Comment: On a sidenote: Your data model is strange. Shouldn't a `PersonID` link to a person table where we find first and last name? With your database design the same person can have different first and last names. I don't think that's intended, is it?

Comment: Ok, I thought the privileges were already stored together as a single value. Looks like the answer below is probably what you need.

Comment: What is the primary key of your table? can you normalize it?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner-This is a view, with Person data in another view that this view uses.  It does make sense that each personID is only for one person.  The key is personID.  There won't be more than one first/last name for each personID., but the opposite might be true.  The same first/last name can have two different personID's if it's 2 different people with the same name.  Other data would show differences, like Middle initial, or Department, etc, that I'm not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show a users rows, provided there does **not exist** a row with a def privilege. Something like

```
SELECT personid, last, first, facility, department, ...
FROM person_by_privilages pp
WHERE facility = 'S'
AND department like ('%P%')
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM person_by_privilages pp2
  WHERE pp2.personid = pp.personid
  AND pp2.facility = 'S'
  AND pp2.department like ('%P%')
  AND pp2.privilages LIKE ('%def%')
);
```

Comment: Golden.  Thank you so much.  Worked very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting Mary Hoff, because there exists a row that matches your conditions. What you can do is aggregate a persons rows and then look whether no rows match or not:

```
SELECT
  personid, last, first, facility, 
  STUFF ( ... department ...) AS departments,
  STUFF ( ... privilages ...) AS privileges
FROM person_by_privilages
WHERE facility = 'S'
AND department like ('%P%')
GROUP BY personid, last, first, facility
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN privilages LIKE ('%def%') THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: It looks like it's returning Hoff privilages where they aren't 'def'.  I see 'abc' and 'cde' in my results. Any other ideas?  I don't want it to return Hoff, just Smith.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right. This doesn't work. I didin't notice that you are showing Departments. So, this query cannot work. I'll think of another solution.

Comment: A solution is to stuff the departments into one string, like you do with the privileges. I've updated my answer accordingly. Or see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data are consistent (regarding Personid, Last, First), you could separate the extraction of person data from their privileges this way

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID, Last,  First, Facility, Department
  FROM person_by_privilages a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM person_by_privilages 
                    WHERE PersonID = a.PersonID and Last = a.Last 
                          and First = a.First and Facility = a.Facility
                          and Department = a.Department
                          and Privilages = 'def')
```

Since you have one row for each privilege, you have to check that there is no row with the privilege you want to exclude.