# Finding user with max(Audit_Date) and date not in range

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on a SQL query where the user's maximum Audit_Date is not in a range, as in they haven't used the system for a long time.  I tried it this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
UserID
,max(Audit_Date)
FROM   RV_USERS RV_USERS
INNER JOIN RV_AUDIT RV_AUDIT ON 
RV_USERS.UserID=RV_AUDIT.UserID
group BY RV_USERS.UserID

AND --it doesn't like the "and" here
not exists(
select *
FROM   RV_USERS RV_USERS
INNER JOIN RV_AUDIT RV_AUDIT ON  ON RV_USERS.UserID=RV_AUDIT.UserID
where 
Audit_Date not between '2019-05-29 00:00:00' and '10/29/2019' 
)
```

I tried to use [not exists, like the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895804/query-not-excluding-people-with-certain-privilege) but it's not working in this case. I get incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND', right before the not exists.  I need to make a view out of this so I think variables and temp tables are out.  It's going to be used in a crystal report and scheduled in Central Management Console.

**Update1: Tried this per answer:
SELECT DISTINCT 
"RV_USERS"."UserID"
,"RV_AUDIT"."Audit_Date"
FROM   "RV_USERS" "RV_USERS" 
INNER JOIN "RV_AUDIT" "RV_AUDIT" ON "RV_USERS"."UserID"="RV_AUDIT"."UserID"

group BY "RV_USERS"."UserID", "RV_AUDIT"."Audit_Date"

HAVING
max("RV_AUDIT"."Audit_Date") < '2019-05-29 00:00:00'

and
"RV_USERS".UserID='me'

This returns me with dates in may, even though I have used the system since May.  I checked that by removing the max date part and see my dates go to today.

**Update2: Tried this per other answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
"RV_USERS"."UserID"
,max("RV_AUDIT"."Audit_Date")
FROM   "RV_USERS" "RV_USERS" 
INNER JOIN "RV_AUDIT" "RV_AUDIT" ON "RV_USERS"."UserID"="RV_AUDIT"."UserID"
WHERE  

not exists(
select *
FROM   "RV_USERS" u2 
INNER JOIN "RV_AUDIT" a2 ON u2."UserID"=a2."UserID"
where 
a2."Audit_Date" not between '2019-05-27 00:00:00' and '10/31/2019' 
)
group BY "RV_USERS"."UserID"
```

This is not returning anything, but we know there are managers that haven't used the system.

**Update 3 per answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
u."UserID"
,max(a."Audit_Date")
FROM   "RV_USERS" u 
INNER JOIN "RV_AUDIT" a ON u."UserID"=a."UserID"
WHERE  
u.UserID not in(

select u2.UserID

FROM   "RV_USERS" u2 
INNER JOIN "RV_AUDIT" a2 ON u2."UserID"=a2."UserID"
where 
a2."Audit_Date" between '2019-05-27 00:00:00' and '10/31/2019' 
)
group BY u."UserID"
```

Comment: Why ***should*** it like `AND`? What condition is it a part of?

Comment: I see your point.  Maybe they could use the "AND" in the link/example because of it not having group by so it was still continuing the where. I have to have group by here because of the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more than one mistakes, here is corrected code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       RV_U.UserID
       , max(RV_U.Audit_Date)
FROM   RV_USERS RV_U
INNER JOIN RV_AUDIT RV_A ON RV_U.UserID=RV_A.UserID
WHERE
NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM   RV_USERS RV_USERS
    INNER JOIN RV_AUDIT RV_AUDIT ON RV_USERS.UserID=RV_AUDIT.UserID
    WHERE Audit_Date not between '2019-05-29 00:00:00' and '10/29/2019' 
)
GROUP BY RV_U.UserID;
```

- Your line `NNER JOIN RV_AUDIT RV_AUDIT ON  ON
  RV_USERS.UserID=RV_AUDIT.UserID` has `ON` two times.
- `GROUP BY` should go on the end
- `AND` should be replaced with `WHERE`

Try to implement this changes.

Comment: Thank you, it isn't erroring out now, but it's returning people that have been on the system since 5-29.  Any ideas? I tried changing the not exists range to between instead of not between.

Comment: Hi @Michele, You are welcome! HAppy to help. Please can you mark this answer as correct first ? And give it up vote ? Thanks! I will check it now.

Comment: If you could edit it so it returns just the ones that have used the system since the date I'd appreciate it.  Even though it's not err-ing out, it's still not correct for some reason.

Comment: @Michele you told me : Thank you, it isn't erroring out now. And now you are asking another question. If this answer is correct for the first question you should mark it as correct and give it up vote. It would be fair...

Comment: @Michele for your second question here is the DEMO (if NOT IN  is not your option try IN instead). Maybe it will help. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1c6596cbb718c85d7cfdef95b2085689

Comment: I like the "not in" idea.  I think it needs to be "between" instead of "not between" in the second half.  Don't you?  To exclude people with dates in the exclusion?

Comment: Well yes if you choose `NOT IN` then only `BETWEEN`. Or if you choose `IN` then go in combination with with `NOT BETWEEN`

Comment: Very cool.  Thanks.  I'm not used to these different (for me) sql expression combinations.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a `having` clause:

```
SELECT UserID, max(Audit_Date)
FROM RV_USERS RV_USERS INNER JOIN
     RV_AUDIT RV_AUDIT 
     ON RV_USERS.UserID = RV_AUDIT.UserID
GROUP BY RV_USERS.UserID
HAVING max(Audit_Date) < '2019-05-29';
```

Your query seems much more complicated than necessary.

Comment: +10  OP specification is not entirely clear, but I suspect that this is the result OP wants to return.

Comment: I like your idea, but when I add and
"RV_USERS".UserID='me' I see 180 rows listing me, even though I've used the system many times since May

Comment: When  take out the max(Audit_Date) part, I do see my dates going up to yesterday.  I'm not sure why this is listing me in May with the max(Audit_Date) part there.

Comment: @Michele . . . I don't understand your comment.  If you filter to one `UserId`, then you should get one row, because this is an aggregation query.

Comment: Ok, if I take out the filter for just me, it's giving everyone in our office and more.  I know they have used the system since 5-29-2019.  I appreciate the help, and if you have any other ideas, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Michele . . . This should not return any users who have had an `Audit_Date` after the specified date.  What is the datatype of `Audit_Date`?  If it is not a date/time time, then you have a data modeling problem, that you should fix.

Comment: Audit_date is datetime.

Comment: @Michele . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle of some sort?  This query cannot return users who have more recent audits.

Comment: I never used db fiddle before.  I tried setting one up like the other answer is using and it isn't giving me sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `and` with `where` clause and put the group by at the last to make the above query run atleast

Comment: Yes i meant that I din see group by before it. Updated